# Error while compiling PHP extension

Tags: php, mongodb, gcc, zend

I'm trying to install a php extension that is written in c and make use of MongoDB c driver.

I have been trying for the last 2 days to compile and install the extension, however, I'm getting the same error.

```
 /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc.a(bson.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `bson_numstrs' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/local/lib/libmongoc.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [thaps.la] Error 1
```

The full log can be found at pastbin: http://pastebin.com/iqpqHYpm

The extension I'm trying to install is at bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/heinep/thaps

I'm using php 5.4 with zend 2.4 apache 2.2 MongoDB c driver v0.5 ubuntu 12.04 64bits

Comment: Just a compiling error not server related issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to install the MongoDB server, not the [c](/questions/tagged/c) driver. Also install the `mongodb-dev` package, as additional development headers/files may be needed. If you need additional help; documents at [mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org) offer detailed instructions for [installing on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) & [PHP driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/PHP+Language+Center).

```
sh ~> sudo apt-get install mongodb-server mongodb-dev
sh ~> sudo pecl install mongo
```

[php5-mongo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/php5-mongo) is also available through Ubuntu's package manager.

```
sh ~> sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```